# 1:1 AND 1:many join in MVC5 model

Tags: entity-framework

We are trying to create a model VENUE that has both a single IMAGE (to use in it's details page) and also a collection of IMAGES for an image slider.
We can do one or the other but adding both ends up with 2x 1:1 relationships.
How do we set up two connections this way within the model?
So basically we have:

> public int? ImageID {get;set;}
>
> public virtual Image DefaultImage {get;set;}

but also want to add:

> public virtual ICollection Images {get;set;}

Or is there a better, more recommended way of doing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using annotations and migrations for our mappings not fluent but turned out to be fairly simple.

```
public int? ImageID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Default Image")]
public virtual Image Image { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your Fluent Api:

```
.HasOptional(v => v.DefaultImage)
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

.HasMany(v => v.Images)
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

this works with the `Venue` model you have in your question and there's no need to have any virtual properties in the `Image` model.